# Are continuous functions on a closed interval nowhere infinite?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, proof-verification, infinity

My intuition says YES. **Am I correct?** The following is the proof of my intuition.

Let a function $f(x)$ be continuous in the interval $[a,b]$ and suppose it is infinite at a point $c$ in the interval.

$\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to0} f(c\ +\Delta x)\ -f(c)= \text{not defined}$

Therefore $f(x)$ is not continuous at $c$

This is a contradiction. Therefore our supposition is incorrect. Therefore $f(x)$ cannot be infinite at point $c$ in the interval. Since $c$ is an arbitrary point, $f(x)$ cannot be infinite at any point in the interval $[a,b]$.

**Is my proof correct?**

Comment: Does being "infinite" for a function at a point means that at that point the limit of the function is $\;\pm\infty\;$ ? This is not a standard term so you should define it.

Comment: Infinity ($\infty$) is not a number, so I am not totally sure what do you mean by a function to be infinite at a point $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, function being "infinite" dosent make sense, but function tending to infinity, or the limit of the function being infinity, does make sense. In this sense, consider $[0,\infty)$, which is closed and let the function be $e^x$, Then, as $x\to\infty$, the function also "tends to infinity".

On the other hand, if the interval were closed and bounded(or compact), your guess is right

Comment: You said "function tending to infinity, or the limit of the function being infinity"... Do you mean "when we approach a point $x=c$, the function $f(x)$ becomes bigger and bigger without limit"?

Comment: @Joe yes, your definition is true for limit at a point. However, for limit of a function at infinity, we have the definition as $\forall \epsilon, x_0\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x-x_0|\gt\epsilon\implies f(x)\gt\epsilon$, then the function is said to be tending to infinity as $x$ tends to infinity

Answer (score 2):

A continuous real function on a closed finite interval is bounded there, and achieves its maximal and minimal values within the interval. These two are the well known Weierstrass Theorems I and II .

I suppose and hope the above answers your question...